FloatBarrier not working for sidenotes
I use tufte-book and have difficulties with using FloatBarrier. I constructed a simple test case and found that it does not work as I understand it:
I assume that at the point of \FloatBarrier the accumulated floats, i.e. sidenotes are output before any new text is issued. In the example, the second paragraph, which should come after the sidenotes are placed, starts immediately after the first.
What I need is a method to clear all accumulated sidenotes (like \clearpage does, but without jump to a new page, as has been asked for by others, but without documenting a solution.)
MWE:
\documentclass{article}  % [nobib]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\begin{document}
    
\section{erster}
    first para \lipsum[1]
    \sidenote{\lipsum[1][2]}
    \sidenote{\lipsum[1][2]}
    \FloatBarrier
    second para     \lipsum[1] % should only start after the sidenotes
just a text

\end{document}


Do you want a big white space pushing your second section? Why don't you add it manually?

For draft-quality output I need a method which does not require manual intervention and not changes in the text which must be adapted after changes. For final versions, manual fine-tuning is required.

The side notes has nothing to do with floats as  figure or table environment of standard classes, although they "float" a bit in the margin of the same page, they are something else. The \FloatBarrier simply is not for that.
As far I know there are not a way to flush accumulated side notes, but there an optional offset argument, so you can control the vertical position of the notes when needed:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\begin{document}
\section{erster}
    first para \lipsum[1]
    \sidenote[][-6cm]{\lipsum[1][2]}
    \sidenote[][-3cm]{\lipsum[1][2]}
    second para     \lipsum[1] % should only start after the sidenotes
just a text
\end{document}


And/or you can place a \sidenotext before the \sidenotemark. This have the advantage that notes are stacked automatically without the risk of overlapping fixing wrong offsets, so only mather the place of the first \sidenotext. In the next MWE, just after the section:
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\begin{document}
\section{erster}
    \sidenotetext{\lipsum[1][2]}
    \sidenotetext{\lipsum[1][2]}
    first para \lipsum[1]\sidenotemark[1]\sidenotemark[2] 
    second para     \lipsum[1] % should only start after the sidenotes
just a text
\end{document}



Yeah. Sorry. I just had a quick look at tufte-common and it appears that sidenotes are done using regular \marginpar, so there might be some hope for adding support to placeins. I notice that sidenotes seem to have their own \vspace rather than relying on \marginparpush, so I'm not sure if anything is feasible.

I was experimenting some more and found that for draft-quality output it would be sufficient to have a clearpage like command, eg. \flushOutput, which would force all output but then continue on the page (ie. not doing the newpage part of clearpage). is such a command available?
